# KEEP duplicated lines using grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am using grep to search a file1 for patterns that are inside file2, this file2 has some duplicated lines, and I can only get them once. How to keep duplicated lines using grep?

**file1.txt**

```
2L  FlyBase mRNA    11009821    11011086    .   -   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0080162;Parent=gene:FBgn0032329;Name=Art8-RA;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0080162

2L  FlyBase ncRNA   11011162    11012135    .   -   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0346761;Parent=gene:FBgn0267425;Name=asRNA:CR45778-RA;biotype=ncRNA;transcript_id=FBtr0346761

2L  FlyBase mRNA    11011312    11012135    .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0080156;Parent=gene:FBgn0250837;Name=dUTPase-RB;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0080156

2L  FlyBase mRNA    11011312    11012135    .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0331195;Parent=gene:FBgn0250837;Name=dUTPase-RC;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0331195

2L  FlyBase mRNA    11011312    11012135    .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0080157;Parent=gene:FBgn0250837;Name=dUTPase-RA;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0080157

2L  FlyBase mRNA    67043   71081   .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0306536;Parent=gene:FBgn0067779;Name=dbr-RC;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0306536

2L  FlyBase mRNA    67043   71390   .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0078100;Parent=gene:FBgn0067779;Name=dbr-RB;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0078100
```

**file2.txt**

```
FBtr0306536

FBtr0078100

FBtr0306536

FBtr0078100
```

**My code:**
`grep 'ID=transcript:' file1.txt | grep -w -f file2.txt`

```
2L  FlyBase mRNA    67043   71081   .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0306536;Parent=gene:FBgn0067779;Name=dbr-RC;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0306536

2L  FlyBase mRNA    67043   71390   .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0078100;Parent=gene:FBgn0067779;Name=dbr-RB;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0078100
```

**--->However, I wish I could have this result:**

```
2L  FlyBase mRNA    67043   71081   .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0306536;Parent=gene:FBgn0067779;Name=dbr-RC;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0306536

2L  FlyBase mRNA    67043   71390   .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0078100;Parent=gene:FBgn0067779;Name=dbr-RB;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0078100

2L  FlyBase mRNA    67043   71081   .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0306536;Parent=gene:FBgn0067779;Name=dbr-RC;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0306536

2L  FlyBase mRNA    67043   71390   .   +   .   ID=transcript:FBtr0078100;Parent=gene:FBgn0067779;Name=dbr-RB;biotype=protein_coding;transcript_id=FBtr0078100
```

Answer (score 0):

how about doing it using a loop?

```
while read line
do
 grep "$line" file1.txt
done < file2.txt
```

Should work assuming you do not have empty lines between the FBtr IDs in file2.txt (in your question, there are empty lines)